# Doubt regarding temperature as average of kinetic energy of a system

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I am in the 11th grade and according to what I have studied in thermodynamics, temperature is the "average" kinetic energy of all molecules in a system whereas thermal energy is the "total" kinetic energy of all molecules in a system.

My understanding of this is that consider there are 3 molecules making up a system (just a thought not real life) with translational kinetic energies of $\rm 21 \ J$,$\rm 22\ J$ and $\rm 23\ J$ ,the temperature must be $\rm 22\ °C$ because average $\rm (21+22+23=66/3=22 \ J=22 °\ C)$ and thermal energy should be 66J without average.

But when I studied kinetic theory of gases the kinetic energy of 1 gas molecule at $\rm 273\ K$ is $\rm 5.66 × 10^{-21} \ J$ derived from the formula $\rm K.E=3/2\ KT$.Even if I multiply this k.e for 1 mole and take the average I don't seem to be getting $\rm 273\ J$ and $\rm 273\ K$.

Comment: Please use LaTeX formatting for formulas and numbers in your post.

Comment: For [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/965370)

Comment: Tempreature is related to the average KE but it is not the KE. Equating the KE in joules to tempreature in kelvin or celsius is nonsense.

Comment: So how do I get temperature when I know kinetic energy?

Comment: Kinetic energy is an attribute of each  particle . Average kinetic energy means one should have the kinetic energies of all the particles in the sample, to have an average of them. You need large numbers, of order to avogadros number to get accurate temperature. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html .

Comment: When you make things very hot it becomes a plasma. Ie the electrons go from ground shell to infinity. When electrical charges accelerate they produce emf in this case blackbody radiation. When atoms electrons are further away from their nucleus the energy increases and they collide and react more often

Answer (score 0):

If a system has a way to store internal energy we call that a degree of freedom. That can include macroscopic degrees of freedom like the stretching of a spring or microscopic degrees of freedom like the velocity of a gas molecule.

Microscopic degrees of freedom include potential energy, like molecular orbitals, as well as kinetic energy. So it is fundamentally wrong to focus exclusively on kinetic energy. Usually this concept of internal degrees of freedom is introduced in the context of ideal gasses, where there is only KE, but that is just an idealization and not a general rule.

> temperature is the AVERAGE kinetic energy of all molecules in a system

The temperature is **proportional** to the average internal energy per degree of freedom, not just KE. The constant of proportionality is Boltzmann’s constant $1.38 \ 10^{−23} \ \mathrm{J/K}$

> whereas thermal energy is the TOTAL kinetic energy of all molecules in a system

The term “thermal energy” is used inconsistently. Some authors refer to the total energy in all of the unknown microscopic degrees of freedom (not just KE). Other authors use the term to refer to the average energy in a single degree of freedom. You need to look at the context to see how it is being used.